# File permissions for kernel have changed in OSX Yosmite, why?

Tags: permissions, kernel

I am working my way through the book Learning Unix for OSX Mountain Lion (I don't have access to the updated version for OSX), in which it demonstrates that using

```
$ ls -l /mach_kernel
```

should produce a response similar to

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root wheel 8190504 Apr 8 22:23 /mach_kernel
```

In OSX Yosemite I understand that `/mach_kernel` has been replaced/moved to `System/Library/Kernels/kernel`. The file permissions for which, appear to be

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  10633544 28 May 19:39 kernel
```

I understand that the `@` symbol after the permissions signified that extended permissions were accessible through `xattr -l`, would this command have shown that in fact the `/mach_kernel` also had execute permissions?

My question is, assuming the execute permissions were not set by someone maliciously, what is the reason for the addition of execute permissions for the kernel?